# Hash Method for doubles with tolerance level

Tags: java, hash, equals

I implemented a equals method as shown below with a tolerance level for doubles.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // Checking for not null and same class etc.
    return approxEqual(this,other);
}

private static boolean approxEqual(final Position p1, final Position p2) {
    double distance = // distance function between positions
    return Double.compare(distance, TOLERANCE) <= 0;
}
```

As I'm using `HashSet`s I need a hash method with the same functionality.
Do you guys have any Idea how to do that?

I know, tolerance levels are not really nice as the equals method should be transitive. But I need to balance measurement inaccuracy.

Comment: This is not equality (it doesn't obey transitivity). It's a fine property to measure, but don't call it equality. And definitely don't abuse the `Object.equals` method like this.

Comment: How would that be possible?  "Equal within a tolerance" isn't transitive, so it doesn't induce a partition.  You therefore can't have a hash code that has the same value for all numbers that are "equal within a tolerance"; unless it has the same value for every number.

Comment: If you're using `HashSet`, then your whole approach is wrong. You need another data structure, ideally one that supports queries by proximity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could **split your data into ranges** and say that everything in some range is equal.
You can do this with rounding (the exact details depends on what level of tolerance you're looking for, for the below you can simply use `floor`).

So if we're splitting into ranges of 1, we can say everything between 0 and 1 (not including 1, i.e. in the range [0,1)) are equal, and everything between 1 and 2 are equal, and so on.

---

This does, however, create a problem where **elements very close to each other can be unequal** if they're in different ranges, e.g., for the above, 0.9999 will not be considered equal to 1.0001.

This problem is not entirely avoidable if you're trying to use only equality (and hashing) for this, as extending these ranges doesn't solve this problem, and trying to make them overlap creates new problems.

Depending on how you're trying to use this, it might be possible to solve the above problem by doing multiple lookups, so you consider 0.9999 both in the [0,1] range as well as the [1,2] range. This would work if you're say trying to do a lookup to find all elements that's within some tolerance of some other element (which isn't quite the same as treating the elements as equal).

If this won't work for you, hashing is probably not the solution you're looking for and you might want to **consider an ordered dataset**, such as a `TreeMap` (or indeed a kd-tree, as mentioned in another answer).

---

This is mostly based on 1D data (i.e. doubles), but it can easily be extended to 2D (square ranges) or 3D (cube ranges) by rounding each dimension. If you're doing multiple lookups as mentioned above, you might need to do not 1 lookup (the closest range), but up to 3 in 2D (the closest square range horizontally and vertically, and the square that's adjacent to both of those), and similarly for 3D.

Answer (score 4):

*Hypothetical*: Assuming your tolerance is 1 for now. That means 0 is equal to 0.8 because their difference is lower than the tolerance. Then lets compare 0.8 and 1.5, they are equal since their difference is 0.7 < 1. That means they will get the same hash value, that means that 0 and 1.5 have the same hash value, repeat that process and *everything* will get the same hash value / be equal.

That does not make sense, does it? You cannot do `equal` or `hashcode` with tolerance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I believe that goes against the very nature of hashes.

A [k-d-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or a binary search are the first thing that comes to mind as alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`.

If you implement the tolerance in the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) / [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) method, then any key lookups / inserts will "snap" to an existing key that's within tolerance.

There is of course still the caveat that order of insertion may affect the result. E.g. if tolerance is 5, and you have the values 2, 6, and 9, then adding 6 first will snap both 2 and 9 to the 6 value, and the result is one key (6), otherwise you end up with two keys (2 and 9) and it's arbitrary whether 6 snaps to 2 or 9.

With tolerance, there is really nothing you can do about such unpredictability, so I believe that's the best solution for your problem.